# Ceramic tile on conrete floor: caulk or grout to cinder block wall

Tags: grout, caulk

I plan on tiling a laundry room concrete floor.
Two adjacent walls are cinder block.

I know NOT to use grout between tiled walls and floors or it will crack.

However, since there should be little or no flexing between the surfaces, can I use grout in this situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't a right way to do this.  In my opinion I would grout the area unless it is razor thin.  In most cases this won't be uniform as a wall isn't exactly flat and so you may end up with a rather large gap in some areas - more than 1/8th inch.  If your grout does crack in the future it looks just fine with a layer of caulk over it.

Answer (score 1):

you know it will crack. Just use flexible caulk.

Comment: I believe you but hope springs eternal.